# Create type definition for method exposed on namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm converting an existing JavaScript application to Typescript. I start with:

```
// file1.js
(function(ns) {
  ns.bar = function() { };
}(window.MyNamespace || {}));
```

```
// file2.js
(function(ns) {
  ns.Item = function() {
    this.doStuff = function() { ns.bar(); };
  }
}(window.MyNamespace || {}));
```

Now I'm converting `file2.js` to TypeScript:

```
module MyNamespace {
  class Item {
    doStuff() {
      MyNamespace.bar(); // This is obviously a problem
    }
  }
}
```

There is a problem with calling `bar`. I understand that converting `file1.js` to TypeScript will make things a lot easier, but that file is quite large in reality so I want to do the conversion next sprint and get a intermediary situation.

How do I solve that? How do I tell tsc that `bar` is a function *on the module itself*?

I've tried `declare var bar: () => void;` inside the `module` and variations thereof, but didn't get it to work so far.

I know I could consider converting those "namespace-functions" to static methods on a class, but that would require rewriting `file1.js` *now*, which I don't want (yet).

I've got a *workaround* like this:

```
module MyNamespace {
  var ns: any = MyNamespace;

  class Item {
    doStuff() {
      ns.bar();
    }
  }
}
```

But that feels a bit off, not in the least because it requires changes *inside* my `class`, whereas I'd prefer to have a bridge between `file2.ts` and `file1.ts` seperate from the final `file2.ts` stuff.

In essence, I feel like I'm writing a `.d.ts` file for my original `file1.js` functionality that will make `file2.ts` work *now*, in a way that can remain unchanged after converting `file1.js` to `.ts`.

Any tips? How do I create a typing for my unconverted `file1.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a declare statement *next* to the module like this:

```
declare module MyNamespace {
    var bar: () => void;
}

module MyNamespace {
  class Item {
    doStuff() {
      MyNamespace.bar(); // This will compile!
    }
  }
}
```

You could (should) remove this temporary declaration of the `bar` method once you've converted file1.js to Typescript